# Select with linq two object from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, select

I've got the following `Log` table

```
int LogID
text Name
datetime CreationTime
text Content
int CreatorID
```

I try to get all the logs created by a concrete `Creator`

```
Creator creator = myDataContext.Creator.Single<Creator>(cr => cr.Name == name);
var query = (from l in myDataContext.Log
            where l.CreatorID == creator.CreatorID
            select l).ToList<Log>();
```

but in the returned list the `Creator` is null.

How can I get a list of logs for a given `Creator`?

Comment: Are you sure you have logs for that CreatorID?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question... Is your Client object being set correctly by the first query. Put a breakpoint on the second query to check the creator variable is being set correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set LoadOptions:

```
DataLoadOptions dataLoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
dataLoadOptions.LoadWith<Log>(l => l.Creator);
myDataContext.LoadOptions = dataLoadOptions;
```

Comment: Why I haven't available Include? Version of .NET or what?

Comment: No, different ORM. Linq-to-SQL isn't Linq-to-EF.

Comment: Uh, ok. Misundarstanding of your post description. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var logs = myDataContext.Logs.Include("Creator").Where(c => c.Creator.Name == name).ToList();
```

Comment: Why I haven't available Include? Version of .NET or what?